# How to create two separate threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have one object list that contains 12 records:

```
var claims = GetClaimbyInventory(job.parameter1,job.parameter2).ToList();
```

I want to create 12 separate threads on `claims` so that each record becomes one separate thread and runs parallel.

```
void processClaim (ClaimEntity claims)
```

Currently I just loop and from the list and send the `claim` to `processClaim` method but it is sequentially and I want to do parallel.

Comment: Please post code you need help with so we can see what you have tried and try to point you in a general direction.  Sounds to me like you are asking about a parallel for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely want to use `Parallel.ForEach`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop for an example.